# IndexOutOfBounds error inserting into sorted list

Tags: java, sorting, exception, arraylist

Could someone tell me why i keep getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`?

`Cheeses` are just an array containing a set of strings.
`Alphabets` is a class containing a single string variable.

I am trying to write a program where the strings are preceded by the starting alphabet.

So there would be an A followed by words starting with the letter A and so on.

```
    public class RecyclerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RecyclerTest obj = new RecyclerTest();
        ArrayList<Object> arr_obj = obj.getRandomSublist(Cheeses.sCheeseStrings, 20);
        // System.out.println(arr_obj.toString()+"");

    }

    ArrayList<Object> getRandomSublist(String[] array, int amount) {
        final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(amount);
        Random random = new Random();
        while (list.size() < amount) {
            list.add(array[random.nextInt(array.length)]);
        }
        Collections.sort(list, new sortList());
        return insert(list);
    }

    class sortList implements Comparator<String> {

        @Override
        public int compare(String s, String t1) {
            return s.compareTo(t1);
        }
    }

    ArrayList<Object> insert(ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
        ArrayList<Object> str = new ArrayList<>();
        int count = arrayList.size();
        System.out.println(arrayList.toString());
        int i = 0;
        while (i < count) {
            // Alphabets alphabets = new Alphabets(arrayList.get(i).substring(0,1));
            String temp = arrayList.get(i).substring(0, 1);
            str.add(temp);
            System.out.println(str.toString());
            System.out.println(i);
            while ((i < count) && (temp.equalsIgnoreCase(arrayList.get(i).substring(0, 1)))) {
                str.add(arrayList.get(i));
                i++;
            }
        }
        str.add(arrayList.get(i));
        // System.out.println(str.size());
        return str;
    }

}  



public class Alphabets {
    String alp;

    public Alphabets(String alp) {
        this.alp = alp;
    }

    public String getAlp() {
        return alp;
    }
}
```

> Original String
>
> [Baby Swiss, Bresse Bleu, Bruder Basil, Charolais,
>   Charolais, Coeur de Chevre, Cold Pack, Fourme de Montbrison, Fresh
>   Mozzarella, Fromage Frais, Havarti, Le Fium Orbo, Loddiswell Avondale,
>   Peekskill Pyramid, Remedou, Ricotta Salata, Samso, Tete de Moine, Trou
>   du Cru, Tymsboro]

```
Output

[B]
    0
    [B, Baby Swiss, Bresse Bleu, Bruder Basil, C]
    3
    [B, Baby Swiss, Bresse Bleu, Bruder Basil, C, Charolais, Charolais, Coeur de Chevre, Cold Pack, F]
    7
    [B, Baby Swiss, Bresse Bleu, Bruder Basil, C, Charolais, Charolais, Coeur de Chevre, Cold Pack, F, Fourme de Montbrison, Fresh Mozzarella, Fromage Frais, H]
    10
    [B, Baby Swiss, Bresse Bleu, Bruder Basil, C, Charolais, Charolais, Coeur de Chevre, Cold Pack, F, Fourme de Montbrison, Fresh Mozzarella, Fromage Frais, H, Havarti, L]
    11
    [B, Baby Swiss, Bresse Bleu, Bruder Basil, C, Charolais, Charolais, Coeur de Chevre, Cold Pack, F, Fourme de Montbrison, Fresh Mozzarella, Fromage Frais, H, Havarti, L, Le Fium Orbo, Loddiswell Avondale, P]
    13
    [B, Baby Swiss, Bresse Bleu, Bruder Basil, C, Charolais, Charolais, Coeur de Chevre, Cold Pack, F, Fourme de Montbrison, Fresh Mozzarella, Fromage Frais, H, Havarti, L, Le Fium Orbo, Loddiswell Avondale, P, Peekskill Pyramid, R]
    14
    [B, Baby Swiss, Bresse Bleu, Bruder Basil, C, Charolais, Charolais, Coeur de Chevre, Cold Pack, F, Fourme de Montbrison, Fresh Mozzarella, Fromage Frais, H, Havarti, L, Le Fium Orbo, Loddiswell Avondale, P, Peekskill Pyramid, R, Remedou, Ricotta Salata, S]
    16
    [B, Baby Swiss, Bresse Bleu, Bruder Basil, C, Charolais, Charolais, Coeur de Chevre, Cold Pack, F, Fourme de Montbrison, Fresh Mozzarella, Fromage Frais, H, Havarti, L, Le Fium Orbo, Loddiswell Avondale, P, Peekskill Pyramid, R, Remedou, Ricotta Salata, S, Samso, T]
    17
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Random;

 public class RecyclerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RecyclerTest obj = new RecyclerTest();
        ArrayList<Object> arr_obj = obj.getRandomSublist(Cheeses.sCheeseStrings, 20);
        // System.out.println(arr_obj.toString()+"");

    }

    ArrayList<Object> getRandomSublist(String[] array, int amount) {
        final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(amount);
        Random random = new Random();
        while (list.size() < amount) {
            list.add(array[random.nextInt(array.length)]);
        }
        Collections.sort(list, new sortList());
        return insert(list);
    }

    class sortList implements Comparator<String> {

        @Override
        public int compare(String s, String t1) {
            return s.compareTo(t1);
        }
    }

    ArrayList<Object> insert(ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
        ArrayList<Object> str = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Object> cc = new ArrayList<>();
        int count = arrayList.size();
          System.out.println(arrayList.toString());

        int i = 0;

     String prv = "";
     int letterscount=0;
      System.out.println(str.size());
        while (i < count) {
              //System.out.println(str.size());
            // Alphabets alphabets = new Alphabets(arrayList.get(i).substring(0,1));
            String temp = arrayList.get(i).substring(0, 1);

             if(!prv.equals(temp))
            {

                str.add(temp);

                int x = 0 ;

                while (temp.equalsIgnoreCase(arrayList.get(x).substring(0, 1))) {

                    if(!prv.equalsIgnoreCase(temp)){
                         str.add(arrayList.get(x));
                    }

                    x++;

                }

                letterscount++;
             } 

            if(!prv.equalsIgnoreCase(temp)){

                   int size = str.size()-letterscount;

                   System.out.println(str.toString());
                   str.add(arrayList.get(i));
                   System.out.println(size);

            }
            prv = temp;

            i++;
        }

        return str;
    }

}  


   class Cheeses {
        static String[] sCheeseStrings = {"Baby Swiss", "Bresse Bleu", "Bruder Basil", 
                "Charolais", "Charolais", "Coeur de Chevre", "Cold Pack", "Fourme de Montbrison",
                "Fresh Mozzarella", "Fromage Frais", "Havarti", "Le Fium Orbo", "Loddiswell Avondale",
                "Peekskill Pyramid", "Remedou", "Ricotta Salata", "Samso", "Tete de Moine", "Trou du Cru",
                "Tymsboro"};

        public Cheeses( ) {

        }
 }

  class Alphabets {
    String alp;

    public Alphabets(String alp) {
        this.alp = alp;
    }

    public String getAlp() {
        return alp;
    }
}
```

Comment: still the same error,it looks like at the end when the inner while loop completes the value of i==count.

Comment: the error in this str.add(arrayList.get(i)); you'r trying to pass i after the loop

Comment: you were right it was that last str.add that was causing the problem,thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this loop:

```
while ((alphabets.getAlp().equalsIgnoreCase(arrayList.get(i).substring(0, 1))) && (i < count)) {
    str.add(arrayList.get(i));
    i++;
}
```

Note how you call `arrayList.get(i)` *before* you check for `i < count`... so if `i == count`, it will blow up on that line. You may just be able to reverse those conditions:

```
while (i < count && alphabets.getAlp().equalsIgnoreCase(arrayList.get(i).substring(0, 1))
```

(I haven't tried to follow the exact details of what you're doing - just solve the immediate problem.)

Comment: That didnt work,i would have expected the size of the new ArrayList str to be more than arrayList but for some reason it is always below 70,

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 70, Size: 70   i keep getting this error

Comment: @JudeFernandes: It doesn't help that you haven't shown *where* the problem is, via the stack trace. Have you tried debugging through the code to work out where the problem is? (The problem I pointed out is at least *one* problem, but there could be others, of course...)

Comment: Sorry about the poor formatting,i still haven't figured that out yet but hope this helps,i edited the program a bit to print some debug messages.

Comment: @Jude: But you still haven't includes the stack trace, or told us wheat happened if/when you tried debugging this...